# Possessive noun for genderless word

Tags: personal-pronouns, genderless-pronouns

I have a genderless word (a student), but I need to use the possessive pronoun for it. I think of four possibilities: their, his/her, her, and its.

- When a student has a process, the student can improve it from *their* experience or other's feedbacks.
- When a student has a process, the student can improve it from *his/her* experience or other's feedbacks.
- When a student has a process, the student can improve it from *her* experience or other's feedbacks.
- When a student has a process, the student can improve it from *its* experience or other's feedbacks.

What are the best, allowable, and non-allowable usage?

Comment: Use anything except *its*. *Their* is acceptable, *his/her* is awkward and old-fashioned, *his* is considered sexist by some, and *her* refreshingly unconventional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The singular "their" is often preferred if you have no other choice.  There are several other options:

1. Use the second person:

   > If as a student, you have a process, you can improve it from your own experience or other's feedback.
2. Use the imperative form:

   > When a student has a process, improve it from experience or other's feedback.
3. Use the passive voice:

   > A student's process can be improved from student experience or other feedback.
4. Reuse the noun:

   > When a student has a process, it can be improved from the student's experience or other feedback.
5. Use the plural:

   > When students develop processes, they can improve them from their experience or other feedback.

If you can it's best to rewrite the sentence to entirely avoid the need for a gendered pronoun.  There is a bit of an "art" to this that improves with practice:

> Student-developed processes can be improved through experience or feedback.

"His/her" is not usually recommended, and using the female singular "her" can be distracting and seem "politically correct". Plus, it's still not "gender-neutral".

Finally (and despite the possible views of school administrations) it's not appropriate to refer to students as *objects* by using "it", even if you don't like them.  :)

[More info](https://wmich.edu/writing/genderbias)